# Pycharm Pro connection to PostgreSQL database via SSH tunnel doesn't work with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pycharm

I have added a PostgreSQL datasource in Pycharm Pro, which uses a SSH tunnel to access to the database, on a distant server accessible via VPN. I want to access this database in my Django project. The database parameters are [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5nR7.png) (the white bar hides the public IP of the distant server) and the SSH parameters [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VQ9u.png) (my username and the server public IP are hidden too).

I use the same [credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5nR7.png) in my *settings.py* file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'rhu4bdd',
        'USER': 'rhu4gres',
        'PASSWORD': <password>,
        'HOST': <public IP>,
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Django returns this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<public IP>" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How can I use my Pycharm database connection in my Django project ?

Thank you,

MB

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
ssh -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432  root@<public IP>
```

after that use 127.0.0.1 as DB host in your Django config.

Comment: Thanks @Dips, I use this, but I get "wrong password", but Im sure it is the good one...

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rhu4gres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rhu4gres"`

Comment: This will definitely open connection to DB server but for password issue you need to check pg_hba and log file .